# how to merge two feature branches in git

Tags: git

I created one feature branch(branchA) from master and made some changes to this feature branchA. Then later I created another feature branchB from branchA. Now I wanted to merge branchA to branchB and delete the branchA.

I have tried the different commands but it didn't work.

Any suggestions. I want delete branchA and branchB should have all the changes in branchA + branchB. so I can merge branchB to master.

Answer (score 0):

I would try following steps:

- commit the changes in `branchA`
- push `branchA` to remote
- then, checkout to `branchB`, run:

  ```
  git rebase HEAD~1
  ```

This step should apply changes made on `branchA` on top of `branchB`.

After that,

- push `branchB` to remote
- merge `branchB` to `master`
- remove `branchA`